# Is that possible to call method that uses "content_tag" from controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-tag

In my Rails 3 application I use Ajax to get a formatted HTML:

```
$.get("/my/load_page?page=5", function(data) {
  alert(data);
});

class MyController < ApplicationController
  def load_page
    render :js => get_page(params[:page].to_i)
  end
end
```

`get_page` uses the `content_tag` method and should be available also in `app/views/my/index.html.erb`.

Since `get_page` uses many other methods, I encapsulated all the functionality in:

```
# lib/page_renderer.rb
module PageRenderer
  ...
  def get_page
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

and included it like that:

```
# config/environment.rb
require 'page_renderer'

# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include PageRenderer
  helper_method :get_page
end
```

But, since the `content_tag` method isn't available in `app/controllers/my_controller.rb`, I got the following error:

```
undefined method `content_tag' for #<LoungeController:0x21486f0>
```

So, I tried to add:

```
module PageRenderer
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper    
  ...
end
```

but then I got:

```
undefined method `output_buffer=' for #<LoungeController:0x21bded0>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

How would you solve this ?

Comment: what if you include: `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper` in your controller. BTW, seems that you use my answer from your helpers questions :)

Comment: @apneadiving: I included `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper` as you can see above. Yes, your answer to my other question seems reasonable, except the fact that `get_page` deals with representation, but defined in controller :)

Comment: Damn, my comment was really useless, sorry, I'll take another look later :)

Comment: @apneadiving: Thanks, I really don't understand what am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpers are really view code and aren't supposed to be used in controllers, which explains why it's so hard to make it happen.

Another (IMHO, better) way to do this would be to build a view or partial with the HTML that you want wrapped around the params[:page].to_i. Then, in your controller, you can use render_to_string to populate :js in the main render at the end of the load_page method. Then you can get rid of all that other stuff and it'll be quite a bit cleaner.

Incidentally, helper_method does the opposite of what you're trying to do - it makes a controller method available in the views.

Answer (score 36):

To answer the proposed question, **ActionView::Context** defines the output_buffer method, to resolve the error simply include the relevant module:

```
module PageRenderer
 include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
 include ActionView::Context    
 ...
end
```

Comment: `undefined method `content_tag' for ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper:Module`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include all of the cruft from those two included modules, another option is to call `content_tag` via `ActionController::Base.helpers`. Here's some code I recently used to achieve this, also utilizing `safe_join`:

```
helpers = ActionController::Base.helpers
code_reactions = user_code_reactions.group_by(&:code_reaction).inject([]) do |arr, (code_reaction, code_reactions_array)|
  arr << helpers.content_tag(:div, nil, class: "code_reaction_container") do
    helpers.safe_join([
      helpers.content_tag(:i, nil, class: "#{ code_reaction.fa_style } fa-#{ code_reaction.fa_icon }"),
      helpers.content_tag(:div, "Hello", class: "default_reaction_description"),
    ])
  end
end
```